# In Java equals, why is a cast required?

Tags: java, equals

I wrote a class to represent matrices from linear algebra and used IntelliJ to implement `equals()`.

In the generated code:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) { return true; }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Matrix matrix = (Matrix) o;  // (*)

    for (int i=0; i<this.values.length; i++) {
        // compare entries
    }
    return true;
}
```

why does IntelliJ cast the object to type `Matrix`  at position (`(*)`), when just above it checked if the classes are the same?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Comment: You receive an argument of type `Object`, but if you are comparing two `Matrix` objects you need to downcast object to the `Matrx` type in order to be able to access its members and check both objects are in fact equal in every way, e.g. the matrix contents.

Answer (score 0):

The casting to `Matrix` is done so later on the method you can access its methods/members and use them for the comparison (based on your logic).

Answer (score 0):

A straight-forward and simple answer is, in Java every class by default extends **Object** class. That is **Object** class is the superclass and **Matrix** here is a subclass of **Object** class. A simple analogy is, All dogs are animals, not all animals are dogs. Hence, to assign an instance of the **Object** class you need to tell, it is really of a **Matrix** class. That's why the class was casted.

Answer (score 0):

**Type casting is necessary for 'assignment', but not for comparison.**

This is the reason for the explicit use of typecasting in the assignment statement

`Matrix matrix = (Matrix) o;`

The object comparison using == works by verifying whether the references to the objects being compared are the same. Comparing merely the references does not need  typecasting.

However, an assignment statement needs to allocate space for the object on the left, so that it can accommodate all values of the object on the right side. For this purpose, a typecast is necessary in the assignment statement.